# Component Body is empty after init event but not from Chrome Console

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I've a weird behaviour going on here. I've built a custom card carousel component as below :

```
<c:carouselComponent aura:id="carousel"
                        iconName="standard:carousel"
                        title="Cards"
                        showTotal="true">

<aura:iteration aura:id="iterator" items="{!v.data}" var="content">
      <c:carouselCardComponent      
                                    title="{!content.title}"
                                    imageSrc="{!content.thumbnail}"
                                     >
      </c:carouselCardComponent>                                                  
</aura:iteration>

</c:carouselComponent>
```

And this is what happens from c:carouselComponent controller in  init handler :

```
onInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    var body = component.get('v.body');
    var cards = [];

    body.forEach(function(el) {
        if (el.getLocalId() === 'iterator') {
            console.log(el.get('v.body'));
            var children = el.get('v.body');
            cards = children;

        } else {
            cards.push(el);
        }
    });
...
```

Nothing is actually showing in the carousel because the carouselComponent body seems to be empty after it's rendered : `console.log(el.get('v.body'))` returns an empty array.

But when i visualize the `el` object **directly from Chrome Console**, `el.get('v.body')` is not an empty array but it contains all the objects created by the `aura:iteration component` .

What is actually happenning? i think i'm missing something and i don't know how to figure it out.

Thank you for any idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`aura:valueInit` is always the first event fired in the [rendering life cycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_lifecycle.htm) for new components, before anything else happens, including rendering anything inside `aura:iteration`. You'd have to wait until at least the first rendering cycle completes. You should be able to simply do something like the following:

```
setTimeout(
  $A.getCallback(
    function() { 
      helper.postRenderHandler(component, event, helper);
    }
  )
);
```

You might also get away with registering an `aura:valueChange` handler on the `body` attribute, but you'll have to be careful to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: The article you linked to explains how to run code after the rendering is completed. Is there a reason you recommend `setTimeout` instead of handling the render event as stated in the article?

Comment: @gNerb because it requires a full render cycle. The components will not exist any time during the first render cycle. This is a pecularity of aura:iteration, which performs its own rendering later.